# Why do I get an error in pycharm but normal in other places

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I run the program in the jupyter notebook and the terminal is normal, but it is not normal to open it with pycharm！
Same tensorflow version and python version, same .py file
I am very puzzled
May be the key code：

```
def generate_batch(feats, labels, batch_size, shuffle, min_queue_examples):

    num_preprocess_threads = 2
    if shuffle:
        feat_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
            [feats, labels],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            #num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3*batch_size,
            min_after_dequeue=min_queue_examples,
            allow_smaller_final_batch=True)
    else:
        feat_batch, label_batch = tf.train.batch(
            [feats, labels],
            batch_size=batch_size,
            #num_threads=num_preprocess_threads,
            allow_smaller_final_batch=True,
            capacity=min_queue_examples + 3*batch_size)
    print(label_batch)
    print(feat_batch)
    return feat_batch, tf.reshape(label_batch,[-1])
```

> OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_1_batch/fifo_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 50, current size 0)
>   [[Node: batch = QueueDequeueUpToV2[component_types=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](batch/fifo_queue, batch/n)]]